Special relativity - constant acceleration
How can I calculate the proper time of an accelerating frame of reference until it reaches a certain velocity relative to the stationary frame (before acceleration)?
For example, I depart from Earth on a spaceship under constant acceleration of 10 m/s2. How long do I need to keep accelerating (as measured on my clock), until an Earthbound observer sees me moving at .87 c relative to him? Or .99995 c? What would be the Earthbound frame time measured from start until the engine cutoff in these cases?
In classical mechanics, 10 m/s2 acceleration over 1000 seconds gives the same final speed relative to start as 100 m/s2 acceleration over 100 seconds, but I'm not sure if the same holds in special relativity and my speed vs. Earth would be the same for example with 10 m/s2 over 30 000 000 seconds as with 300 m/s2 over 1 000 000 seconds (acceleration and time measured using travelling clock).
Edit: To keep it simple, I'm only interested in special relativity point of view, not how the acceleration itself also affects the clock. I believe that with small values such as 1g the acceleration-induced time dilation can be ignored.

This question is similar to: Proper time for an accelerating object. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As seen in this lecture, the expression of velocity in terms of (constant) proper acceleration $\alpha$ is given by
$$v(\tau) = \frac{\alpha\tau}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{\alpha^2\tau^2}{c^2}}}$$
Where $v$ is the proper velocity and $\tau$ the proper time. If we set $v = \beta c$ for $0 \leq \beta \leq 1$ a percentage of the speed of light
$$\beta c\sqrt{1 + \frac{\alpha^2\tau^2}{c^2}} = \alpha\tau$$
Squaring both sides and rearranging we find
$$\tau = \frac{\beta c}{\alpha\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}}$$
If $\tau$ is your proper time, then we can find the proper time $t$ of an observer at rest with respect to you as
$$t = \gamma\tau$$
Given $\alpha = 10 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}$ and $c = 3 \times 10^8\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$, the solutions are:

For $\beta = 0.87$

$$\tau = \frac{0.87 \times 3 \times 10^8}{10 \times \sqrt{1 - 0.87^2}} = 52935622.91 \text{s}$$
$$t = \gamma \tau = 2.028 \times 52935622.91 = 107363225.0122\text{s} $$

For $\beta = 0.99995$

$$\tau = \frac{0.99995 \times 3 \times 10^8}{10 \times \sqrt{1 - 0.99995^2}} = 2999887498.8280416 \text{s}$$
$$t = \gamma \tau = 100.0013 \times 2999887498.8280416 = 299992499812.4827\text{s} $$

You have a mistake: you incorrectly assume that you have a single fixed $\gamma$. You actually will have to integrate that.

This also had me wondering - if you can transform between frames as simply as Antoniou said, merely multiplying traveller's proper time by gamma based on final velocity. Seemed a bit simple.

@naturallyInconsistent damn, that’s true

All the necessary formulas describing constant proper acceleration can be found in the article Hyperbolic motion.

I was specifically wondering why does gamma of coordinate speed converge towards the multiple of c in proper speed as the speed increases - e. g. 0.99995 c coordinate speed has gamma 100, and also the proper velocity of traveller is 100 c. At lower speeds, say 0.87 c, gamma is 2 but proper velocity just 1.77 c. Somehow, my intuition was that proper velocity should be exactly gamma-multiple of c.

Now that I think about it, poper velocity (in terms of multiples of c), should be gamma times coordinate velocity... which seems to be the case.
